# Is it allowed to sacrifice Chicken or fish for Eid Al Adha

Tags: eid, dhabihah, sacrifice

Since Chicken is a halal bird which is eligible for Zabiha, can it be used as a sacrifice for Eid Al Adha? And what about fish which does not require a Zabiha?

Comment: IN area where I live we considering Kurban (sacrifice during Eid Al Adha) as [Wajib not fard][1]. You shoud firt seek for an answer. Hwo is obligatory to do sacrifice and when. That Maybe give you answer abaut your question

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wajib

Answer (score 7):

The predominant opinion is that only the *an'aam* animals (grazing livestock, e.g. goats or cattle) are valid for *udhiyah*.  Despite the fact that fish and poultry were known during the time of the prophet, it is not reported that he ever sacrificed such, or allowed his companions to do so, for Eid.

See also: http://www.islam-qa.com/en/71275